# CSS Hover Text Changing Color With Button

Tags: html, css

So, it's pretty easy to set a hover over effect for an element. But what I want is when the user hovers over a button that has text in it, to make the button turn from black to white and the text from white black at the same time. Instead of two separate elements. How should I do this?

Thanks!

```
#signUpBox {
    width: 150px;
    height: 47px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 25px;
    border-radius: 2px;
}

#signUpBox:hover {
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

h3 {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: -35px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-size: 17px;
}
```

Comment: ...in five minutes you got 5 near identical answers... seems like you know what to do! :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure how you have the code set up but this would work on a div with an `onclick` function attached as a button:

```
#signUpBox {
    width: 150px;
    height: 47px;
    border: solid 1px #000;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 25px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    color:#000;
    background:#fff;

}

#signUpBox:hover {
    background: #000;
    color:#fff;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="signUpBox">This is a test</div>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/BWnta/)

Comment: The div was the problem! Thanks! I'll answer this up in 6 minutes. I have to wait.

Answer (score 2):

```
#signUpBox:hover {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    color:#000000;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can do

```
#signUpBox:hover h3 {
  color: #000;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/fB7ee/1/)

Answer (score 2):

change text color using `color` property on hover.

```
#signUpBox:hover {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
}
```

Here is a [demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/nmMJy/1/)

Comment: color is to be made black else nothing will be visible.

Comment: @Joseph: see my demo fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

```
#signUpBox {
    width: 150px;
    height: 47px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 25px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    background: #000000;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

#signUpBox:hover {
    background: #ffffff;
    color: #000000;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L6G5P/1/)